# Nodered httpauth node File type credential

Tags: node-red

I try to create a simple REST Server using Nodered v0.18.
To protect the node i download node-red-contrib-httpauth which can offer Basic credential to access http node. Pretty normal at this stage.

So the node

INPUT:HTTP -> httpauth -> OUTPUT:HTTP

INPUT:HTTP properties

```
Method = GET
URL = /rest/test.json
Name = Auth
```

I would want to create multiple login username/password pair. So the best configuration in httpauth is using "File".

I had created a .txt file with these content

```
username1:realm1:password1
username2:realm1:password2
username3:realm1:password3
```

Store in E:\somefilename.txt

Then I Add new node-red-contribs-httpauthfile

```
Name = anyname
Auth Type = Basic
Realm = realm1
File = E:\somefilename.txt
```

In Edit HTTP auth node page

```
Name = anyname
Auth Type = Basic
Realm = realm1
Username = 
Password = 
Hashed = false or untick
```

Then I go to URL http://thisismytestdomain.com:1880/rest/test.json
Basic credential dialog pop up "at least this part working"

I try to put username1, username2 cannot log in or the wrong credential. Then it goes through with username3
I try to change the hierarchy like

```
username3:realm1:password3
username2:realm1:password2
username1:realm1:password1
```

It always the bottom one get authenticated.

Not sure why. Try to google and go to GitHub to understand the code. No luck
The code in GitHub looks logic and should be working but not sure why it always able to pick the last entry only.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess, because I haven't actually tried it.

Looking at the source code, [here](https://github.com/endemecio02/node-red-contrib-httpauth/blob/master/nodes/http-auth-file.js) it splits the lines in the file using "\n". On the assumption your file has CR/LF endings, the first password would be suffixed with a CR, and the 2nd to 2nd-last usernames would be prefixed with a CR. And therefore the only one which would be interpreted correctly is the last - which is what you're seeing.

If this is the case, you would have to edit your file to have Unix-style line endings (just LF) rather than DOS/Windows-style (CR/LF).

By the way, somebody called `oups13` (is this you?) raised an issue on this in June 2018 which has gone unanswered (see https://github.com/endemecio02/node-red-contrib-httpauth/issues/5). So you're not the only one with the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response, before I post I try to search if anyone has the same issue. Opus13 is not me. Yes, I did see that question remain unanswered so I post it here in hope to get some light. I would try and post here the result if it solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Glad it's working. You should accept the answer then to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to try with Nodered v0.18 with httpauth V1.0.12
*hopefully in a future update this issue will be solved.

Thanks to Micheal for pointing it out and yes the reason only last username/password be selected is because of DOS/Windows Line Ending CRLF.

So people who use Unix might have no problem but I using windows 10 and notepad. Notepad only has line ending, CRLF. So i had to download notepad++,

Go to Edit->EOL onversion-> UNIX/OSX format

For extra precaution, I save file with UTF-8 encoding. (remember notepad save as ANSI encoding).

then I put the file in E:\unixEOL.txt

Then i go to httpauth node then point to this new files. Now i can access all 3 username & password pairs.